# jquery two replace functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I am not sure why item count parentheses aren't being removed in this tiny fiddle example.

EDIT: Here is my result from looking at the working answer.

```js
$.fn.itemcount = function(){
     var text = $(this).text();
     text = text.replace("(","").replace(")","");
     $(this).text(text);
};

$("#prc").itemcount();


$.fn.sidecartcost = function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.replace("Your sub total is", "").replace(". ", "");
  $(this).text(text);
};



$('.SideCartCost').sidecartcost();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="prc">(7 Items)</div>
<div class="blank">Woo</div>
<div class="SideCartCost">Your sub total is $300.03. </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not replacing the html/text of the div like so http://jsfiddle.net/x5jeL/1/